# Magnific Pop-Up does not work once I deploy to server

Tags: firebase, gulp, web-deployment, magnific-popup, nunjucks

I am using Google's Web Starter Kit to develop a website. When I am running gulp to watch local changes all files seem to be working fine, including Magnific Pop-Up. The problem starts when I deploy to the server and the Pop-Up JavaScript file just disappears leaving some HTML disfunctional.

I've been trying to find a solution all day long, but I am stuck in the same place, any help is appreciated. If you need any code, file or screenshot just tell me.

Here is the layout.njk where CSS and JavaScript is referenced in the meta and body:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Your styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
{% block headincludes -%}{%- endblock %}


{% block body -%}
<div class="c-site__frame">
  {% include 'partials/_header.njk' %}
  <div class="c-site__content">
  {% block main %}{% endblock main %}
  </div>
</div>
{%- endblock body %}


{%- block bottomincludes %}{%- endblock bottomincludes %}
<!-- build:js /scripts/main.min.js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/libs/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/libs/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->


<!-- Built with love using Web Starter Kit -->
```

Comment: Rather than an image, is it not possible to copy and paste the code as text in the question?

Comment: Sorry yes, I'm new here, does not justify it but I thought it could be visually better. Sorry.

Comment: Please click the "edit" link under your question and replace the picture of code with the actual code. If you want to learn how to have syntax highlighting in your code, click the little ? at the top of the editor.

Comment: @satotzky an image is not useful for anyone wanting to replicate the issue

Comment: I replaced the picture with the actual code @FrankvanPuffelen